# Can't read $_SESSION variable?

Tags: php, session

I'm not sure what's wrong - I tried passing a variable from one php page to another through the SESSION global variable, but it didn't seem to work. Here's what I did:

**Flow**: Form submission --> login.php, if successful, redirect to --> chat.php

And basically, I can't pass SESSION variables from login.php to chat.php.

Here's the code:

**login.php**

```
<?php
session_start(); // pass on variables

// Pass on variables
$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];

// some code here

if ( mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0 ) { 
    // some code here
} else {
    // some code here
        $url = "./chat.php";
        $js = "<script>window.location = '{$url}'</script>"; 
        echo $js;
}
```

**chat.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

$username = $_SESSION['username'];

echo $username;
?>
```

Here are some assumptions:

1. `$_POST['username]` is correct.
2. The rest of the code that's not displayed in **login.php** executes correctly.
3. `echo "works!";` works in chat.php when I added it after the echo line, so I'm pretty sure it's just the variable that's wrong.
4. There's no other html code outside of the `<?php ?>` tags.

Would appreciate some ideas.

Thanks!

Comment: *"Here are some assumptions:"* Don't assume. Check! Does `$_POST['username']` really have a value?

Comment: Have you debugged this in any way?

Comment: @GolezTrol - yes I checked it, it works.

Comment: @RonniSkansing - well, as GolezTrol pointed out, I checked that the $_POST['username'] had a valid variable before it redirected, tried echo-ing another statement in chat.php, but it didn't work.

Comment: B.t.w. You can use `header('Location:')` to redirect to another page. No need to use Javascript for that.

Comment: @GolezTrol thanks for the tip, but that doesn't really answer my question.

Comment: I know. That's why it's a comment.

Comment: @blazonix did you dump the session array on both pages? I was trying to point out that the question is lacking debug/variable content info. Also when I say debug I meant xdebug or similar. If xdebug is too much, start by using var_dump($varToInspect); die; to check the variables, not echo.

Comment: Another thing, check what session_start() return to that sessions are supported. as php 5.3 `If a session fails to start, then FALSE is returned. Previously TRUE was returned.`

Comment: @RonniSkansing For some reason, it now works...I maybe it's a cache problem? Also, why wouldn't sessions be supported?

Comment: @blazonix Sessions are supported.

Comment: @blazonix Glad it worked, do not think it was a cache problem. This is a classic "it worked before and I did not change the code" or reverse "It did not work, now all of a sudden it works.". Most oftenly I experience as the developer being unaware of minor changes they made or did not make; for example forgetting to save.

Comment: @RonniSkansing I might have overlooked something, anyhow, thanks for putting up with such a beginner's question and some practical ideas. :)

Comment: @blazonix: Have you tried turning the server off and on again?

Comment: @hakre again the problem is resolved now, but I host my site else where, not on my servers

Comment: @blazonix: Next to the truth it covers, it also transports this running gag: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nn2FB1P_Mn8&feature=kp

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. I think this will work in chat.php

```
 <?php
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
echo $username;
?>
```

You can check your session by `print_r($_SESSION);`

Answer (score -1):

Session variables fail to work in cases where the apache running on your systems cant create the file it needs to store session variable.
grant permissions to the respective folder they are and set the group owner to www-data.
and at the end of your php code add this session_commit();
or session_write_close();

Comment: I'm sorry what do you mean by "the apache"?

Comment: what system are you using?

Comment: This is only one of the many reasons why things can fail. Session variables also fail in case you pull the power-plug from the server.

Comment: I should mention that the question is resolved now, but I use hostgator, so Linux CentOS

Comment: i highly doubt that he pulls the plug just before redirection.